# Retrieving Alternating Values

Tags: query, order-by

I have a column with two values in my database, I want to retrieve the two values alternately, for example I have:

```
name   itemcode
----------
 A       1
 B       2
 C       2
 D       2
 E       1
 F       1
```

I want to display them as:

```
name itemcode
----------
A      1
B      2
E      1
C      2
F      1
D      2
```

Comment: Welcome to Database Administrators! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for SQL Server. This does work if you have `itemcode` 3, 4, etc. and not just 1 and 2.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test]
(
    name char(1) NOT NULL,
    itemcode tinyint NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test](name, itemcode)
    VALUES ('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 2), ('D', 2), ('E', 1), ('F', 1);


SELECT
    t.name,
    t.itemcode
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            name,
            itemcode,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY itemcode ORDER BY name) AS RowNum
            FROM [dbo].[Test]
    ) t
    ORDER BY
        t.RowNum,
        t.itemcode;
```